# How can I install IMO Messenger on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, instant-messaging

I know that there are other programs (Skype, etc.), but I need namely IMO Messenger.

Comment: Till now, virtual Machine is the one way. Have an Android OS in your VM and install IMO on it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no official Linux client on the [IMO Messenger web site](https://imo.im/) and as far as Google tells me there's no third-party implementation of it either.

You may be able to [set up Android inside a virtual machine](/q/307805/175814) and install the [Android version of IMO Messenger](https://imo.im/download/imo.im-latest.apk).

Comment: Or you can use IMO linux alternatives [see](https://alternativeto.net/software/imo/?platform=linux)